# Editing a specific row in a dynamic table

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've been stuck with this problem for a while now and almost got it to work, but I'm left with an issue I cannot solve or find a solution anywhere.
So I'm trying to make an application which helps users log certain data - it all works on a table, adding rows and deleting them works just fine, but I have a problem with editing them.

At the end of each row, there are 2 buttons - delete and edit.

Edit pops up a modal, which should (and it does as far as I know) display inputs with values read from a specific table row. When you do this for the first time after reloading it works fine, but afterward, if you have more than one table rows it just starts to clean up these tr's upon submitting an edit of a row.

There's clearly a problem with logic, and I just cannot solve it. Most likely it can be found in this block

```
Record.prototype.addRow = function(){
    let newLog = document.createElement('tr');
    newLog.setAttribute('id',idContainer);
    idContainer++;
    recordTable.appendChild(newLog);
    //store values and add them to each td 
    let valueStorage = [this.time,this.latitude,this.longitude,this.heading,
    this.speed,this.wind,this.sea,this.visibility,this.remarks];
    for (let i=0; i<9;i++) {
        let tableData = document.createElement('td');
        newLog.appendChild(tableData);
        tableData.textContent = valueStorage[i];
    }
    //add 2 buttons - delete and edit
    let deleteBtn = document.createElement('button');
    deleteBtn.setAttribute('class','new-record__delete-row-btn')
    newLog.appendChild(deleteBtn);
    let editBtn = document.createElement('button');
    editBtn.setAttribute('class','new-record__edit-row-btn')
    newLog.appendChild(editBtn);
     //adding functionality to edit/delete btns
        function editThisRow(e){
            //on pop up display values from the edited row
            let popUpHeading = document.querySelector('.new-record__popup h2');
            let thisRow = e.target.parentNode;
            let editStorage = [];
            for(let i = 0; i < 9; i++){
                editStorage.push(thisRow.childNodes[i].textContent);
            }
            editStorage[1]=editStorage[1].replace(/([A-Z])/,"");
            editStorage[2]=editStorage[2].replace(/([A-Z])/,"");
            for(let i = 0; i <8; i++){
                newRecordInputs[i].value = editStorage[i];
            }
                remarks.value = editStorage[8];
            popUpHeading.textContent = 'Edit your record!'
            openNewRecordPopup();
            //adding event listener to the record edit button, so that it applies changes
            const recordEditBtn = document.querySelector('#edit-record')
            newRecordSubmitBtn.style.display = "none";
            recordEditBtn.style.display = "block";
            recordEditBtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
                let thisRowTds = thisRow.childNodes;
                for(let i = 0; i < 8; i++){
                    thisRowTds[i].textContent = newRecordInputs[i].value
                }
                thisRowTds[8].textContent = remarks.value;
                closeNewRecordPopup();
                popUpHeading.textContent = 'Fill out inputs below to make a new record';
                newRecordSubmitBtn.style.display = "block";
                recordEditBtn.style.display = "none";
                sortRecords();
            })
        }
    deleteBtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        newLog.remove();
    })
    editBtn.addEventListener('click',editThisRow);
}
```

All the code needed and live example can be found on GitHub:
https://github.com/michynow/electronic-ship-log-book 
https://michynow.github.io/electronic-ship-log-book/

quick note: This is not designed for mobile use, and I really would appreciate vanilla JS solutions, without lib's or frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All edit clicks keep on stacking in below button:

```
const recordEditBtn = document.querySelector('#edit-record')
```

I have changed it to have fresh event handler always like this:

```
let oldRecordEditBtn = document.querySelector('#edit-record')
let recordEditBtn = oldRecordEditBtn.cloneNode(true);
oldRecordEditBtn.parentNode.replaceChild(recordEditBtn, oldRecordEditBtn);
```

So now below snippet is working fine for your issue:

```js
//Set ship header and type
const shipDetailsBtn = document.querySelector('.ship-details__button');
const shipDetailsClosingBtn = document.querySelector('#ship-details__popup-closing-btn');
const shipDetailsPopUp = document.querySelector('.ship-details__popup');
const shipTypeSpan = document.querySelector('#ship-type-span');
const shipNameSpan = document.querySelector('#ship-name-span');

//opening of a form
shipDetailsBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  shipDetailsPopUp.style.visibility = "visible";
  disableButtons();
})
//disabling of button operation when popup is open;
function disableButtons() {
  voyageDetailsBtn.disabled = true;
  newRecordBtn.disabled = true;
  shipDetailsBtn.disabled = true;
}

function enableButtons() {
  voyageDetailsBtn.disabled = false;
  newRecordBtn.disabled = false;
  shipDetailsBtn.disabled = false;
}
//closing of a form
shipDetailsClosingBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  shipDetailsPopUp.style.visibility = "hidden";
  enableButtons();
})

//pop up input selection
const shipTypeSelect = document.querySelector('#ship-type');
const shipDetailsPopUpSubmit = document.querySelector('#ship-details-submit-btn');

//Submitting of ship details
shipDetailsPopUpSubmit.addEventListener('click', () => {
  shipDetailsPopUp.style.visibility = "hidden";
  shipTypeSpan.textContent = shipTypeSelect.options[shipTypeSelect.selectedIndex].value + " ";
  shipNameSpan.textContent = document.querySelector('#ship-name-input').value;
  enableButtons();
  shipDetailsBtn.textContent = "Edit ship details";
})

//date and destination pop up form
const voyageDetailsBtn = document.querySelector('.voyage-details__button');
const voyageDetailsPopUp = document.querySelector('.voyage-details__popup');
const voyageDetailsClosingBtn = document.querySelector('#voyage-details__popup-closing-btn');
voyageDetailsBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  voyageDetailsPopUp.style.visibility = "visible";
  disableButtons();
})

//Update date and destination rows
const dateSpan = document.querySelector('#date-span');
const destinationSpanFrom = document.querySelector('#dest-span__from');
const destinationSpanTo = document.querySelector('#dest-span__to');
const voyageDetailsSubmit = document.querySelector('#voyage-details__submit-btn');
const destFromInput = document.querySelector('#ship-destination-input__from');
const destToInput = document.querySelector('#ship-destination-input__to');
voyageDetailsSubmit.addEventListener('click', () => {
  dateSpan.textContent = " " + document.querySelector('#date-input').value;
  //prevent empty inputs on destination form
  if (destFromInput.value !== "" || destToInput.value !== "") {
    destinationSpanFrom.textContent = " " + destFromInput.value + ' to: ';
    destinationSpanTo.textContent = destToInput.value;
    voyageDetailsBtn.textContent = "Edit date and destination";
    voyageDetailsPopUp.style.visibility = "hidden";
    enableButtons();
  } else {
    alert('Please fill in voyage details!');
  }

})
//remember to add a default attribute setting the current date as placeholder in date form;

//closing of a voyage details pop up
voyageDetailsClosingBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  voyageDetailsPopUp.style.visibility = "hidden";
  enableButtons();
})
//add new data pop up opening / closing
const newRecordBtn = document.querySelector('.new-record__btn');
const newRecordPopUp = document.querySelector('.new-record__popup');
const newRecordSubmitBtn = document.querySelector('#new-record__submit-btn');
const recordTable = document.querySelector('.records-table');
newRecordBtn.addEventListener('click', openNewRecordPopup);

function openNewRecordPopup() {
  newRecordPopUp.style.visibility = "visible";
  disableButtons();
}
const newRecordClosingBtn = document.querySelector('#new-record__popup-closing-btn');

function closeNewRecordPopup() {
  newRecordPopUp.style.visibility = "hidden";
  enableButtons();
}
newRecordClosingBtn.addEventListener('click', closeNewRecordPopup);

// store input values in an array, then pass it to  all created td's
let newRecordInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.new-record__popup input');
let remarks = document.querySelector('textarea');

function clearInputs() {
  for (let i = 0; i < newRecordInputs.length; i++) {
    newRecordInputs[i].value = "";
    remarks.value = "";
  };
}

newRecordSubmitBtn.addEventListener('click', addRecord);

class Record {
  constructor(time, latitude, longitude, heading, speed, wind, sea, visibility, remarks) {
    this.time = time;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.heading = heading;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.wind = wind;
    this.sea = sea;
    this.visibility = visibility
    this.remarks = remarks;
    this.addRow();
  }
}
//set id for each row
let idContainer = 0;
Record.prototype.addRow = function() {
  let newLog = document.createElement('tr');
  newLog.setAttribute('id', idContainer);
  idContainer++;
  recordTable.appendChild(newLog);
  //store values and add them to each td 
  let valueStorage = [this.time, this.latitude, this.longitude, this.heading,
    this.speed, this.wind, this.sea, this.visibility, this.remarks
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    let tableData = document.createElement('td');
    newLog.appendChild(tableData);
    tableData.textContent = valueStorage[i];
  }
  //add 2 buttons - delete and edit
  let deleteBtn = document.createElement('button');
  deleteBtn.setAttribute('class', 'new-record__delete-row-btn')
  newLog.appendChild(deleteBtn);
  let editBtn = document.createElement('button');
  editBtn.setAttribute('class', 'new-record__edit-row-btn')
  newLog.appendChild(editBtn);
  //adding functionality to edit/delete btns
  let editThisRow = function(e) {
    //on pop up display values from the edited row
    let popUpHeading = document.querySelector('.new-record__popup h2');
    let thisRow = e.target.parentNode;
    let editStorage = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      editStorage.push(thisRow.childNodes[i].textContent);
    }
    editStorage[1] = editStorage[1].replace(/([A-Z])/, "");
    editStorage[2] = editStorage[2].replace(/([A-Z])/, "");
    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      newRecordInputs[i].value = editStorage[i];
    }
    remarks.value = editStorage[8];
    popUpHeading.textContent = 'Edit your record!'
    openNewRecordPopup();
    //adding event listener to the record edit button, so that it applies changes
    let oldRecordEditBtn = document.querySelector('#edit-record')
    let recordEditBtn = oldRecordEditBtn.cloneNode(true);
    oldRecordEditBtn.parentNode.replaceChild(recordEditBtn, oldRecordEditBtn);
    newRecordSubmitBtn.style.display = "none";
    recordEditBtn.style.display = "block";
    recordEditBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      let thisRowTds = thisRow.childNodes;
      for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        thisRowTds[i].textContent = newRecordInputs[i].value
      }
      thisRowTds[8].textContent = remarks.value;
      closeNewRecordPopup();
      popUpHeading.textContent = 'Fill out inputs below to make a new record';
      newRecordSubmitBtn.style.display = "block";
      recordEditBtn.style.display = "none";
      sortRecords();
    })
  }
  deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    newLog.remove();
  })
  editBtn.addEventListener('click', editThisRow);
}


function addRecord() {
  //selecting all input values and storing them in an object
  let timeValue = document.querySelector('#new-record__UTC-time').value;
  let northOrSouth = document.querySelector('.north-south');
  let northOrSouthValue = northOrSouth.options[northOrSouth.selectedIndex].value;
  let latitudeValue = document.querySelector('#new-record__latitude').value + " " + northOrSouthValue;
  let eastOrWest = document.querySelector('.east-west');
  let eastOrWestValue = eastOrWest.options[eastOrWest.selectedIndex].value;
  let longitudeValue = document.querySelector('#new-record__longitude').value + " " + eastOrWestValue;
  let headingValue = document.querySelector('#new-record__heading').value;
  let speedValue = document.querySelector('#new-record__SOG').value;
  let windValue = document.querySelector('#new-record__wind-force').value;
  let seaValue = document.querySelector('#new-record__sea-state').value;
  let visibilityValue = document.querySelector('#new-record__visibility').value;
  let anotherRecord = new Record(timeValue, latitudeValue, longitudeValue,
    headingValue, speedValue, windValue, seaValue, visibilityValue, remarks.value);
  closeNewRecordPopup();
  clearInputs();
  sortRecords();
}

//function for sorting out table rows by time dynamically upon edit or new record
function sortRecords() {
  let rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch;
  switching = true
  while (switching) {
    switching = false;
    rows = recordTable.rows;
    for (i = 2; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      shouldSwitch = false;
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
      if (x.textContent > y.textContent) {
        shouldSwitch = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  z-index: 0;
  padding-top: 2vh;
  /*height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;*/
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(50%, white), to(#347deb));
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 50%, #347deb);
  position: relative;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}

header p,
header .destination {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 5vw;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.records-table-container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 60vh;
  margin: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  background-color: #faf6c3;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -1px 22px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px -1px 22px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.records-table-container .new-record__delete-row-btn,
.records-table-container .new-record__edit-row-btn {
  padding: 0.3rem;
  width: 60px;
  margin: 0.1rem;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #963c2c;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s all;
  transition: 0.3s all;
}

.records-table-container .new-record__delete-row-btn:hover,
.records-table-container .new-record__edit-row-btn:hover {
  background-color: #803325;
}

.records-table-container .new-record__delete-row-btn::after,
.records-table-container .new-record__edit-row-btn::after {
  content: "Delete";
}

.records-table-container .new-record__edit-row-btn {
  background-color: #5a51d6;
}

.records-table-container .new-record__edit-row-btn::after {
  content: "Edit";
}

.records-table-container .new-record__edit-row-btn:hover {
  background-color: #4f47bf;
}

.records-table-container table,
.records-table-container th,
.records-table-container td,
.records-table-container tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px 2px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}

.records-table-container .table__input-general-description {
  width: 40vw;
}

.operation-buttons {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.operation-buttons .new-record__btn {
  border: none;
  background-color: #4fa867;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s;
  transition: background 0.3s;
}

.operation-buttons .new-record__btn:hover {
  background-color: #3f8a53;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.operation-buttons .export-button {
  border: none;
  background-color: #963c2c;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s;
  transition: background 0.3s;
}

.operation-buttons .export-button:hover {
  background-color: #803325;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.operation-buttons .ship-details__button {
  border: none;
  background-color: #5a51d6;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s;
  transition: background 0.3s;
}

.operation-buttons .ship-details__button:hover {
  background-color: #4f47bf;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.operation-buttons .voyage-details__button {
  border: none;
  background-color: #88b33e;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s;
  transition: background 0.3s;
}

.operation-buttons .voyage-details__button:hover {
  background-color: #739636;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ship-details__popup {
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 9;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 60vw;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.ship-details__popup #ship-details__popup-closing-btn {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: darkred;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.ship-details__popup form {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 40%;
  min-height: 25vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}

.ship-details__popup form input {
  text-align: center;
}

.ship-details__popup select {
  text-align-last: center;
  padding: 0.1rem;
}

.ship-details__popup #ship-details-submit-btn {
  border: none;
  background-color: #31508f;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s;
  transition: background 0.3s;
}

.ship-details__popup #ship-details-submit-btn:hover {
  background-color: darkred;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.voyage-details__popup {
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 9;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 60vw;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.voyage-details__popup form {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 40%;
  min-height: 25vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}

.voyage-details__popup form input {
  text-align: center;
}

.voyage-details__popup #date-input {
  padding-left: 15%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.voyage-details__popup #voyage-details__popup-closing-btn {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: darkred;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.voyage-details__popup #voyage-details__submit-btn {
  border: none;
  background-color: #31508f;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s;
  transition: background 0.3s;
}

.voyage-details__popup #voyage-details__submit-btn:hover {
  background-color: darkred;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.new-record__popup {
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 9;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 60vw;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  top: 15%;
  margin: auto;
}

.new-record__popup form {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 40%;
  min-height: 25vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}

.new-record__popup form input {
  text-align: center;
}

.new-record__popup #new-record__popup-closing-btn {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: darkred;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.new-record__popup #new-record__submit-btn {
  border: none;
  background-color: #31508f;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s;
  transition: background 0.3s;
  width: 40%;
  margin: auto;
}

.new-record__popup #new-record__submit-btn:hover {
  background-color: darkred;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.new-record__popup #edit-record {
  border: none;
  background-color: #31508f;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s;
  transition: background 0.3s;
  width: 40%;
  margin: auto;
  display: none;
}

.new-record__popup #edit-record:hover {
  background-color: darkred;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.new-record__popup form {
  width: auto;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 0.8rem;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.new-record__popup form #new-record__remarks {
  resize: none;
  height: 3rem;
  padding: 0.2rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Your ship's log book.</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Electronic log book of your ship">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1><span id="ship-type-span"></span><span id="ship-name-span">Ship's name</span> logbook</h1>
    <div class="date-destination-div">
      <p>Date:<span id="date-span"></span></p>
      <p>
        Voyage from: <span id="dest-span__from"></span><span id="dest-span__to"></span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="records-table-container">
    <table class="records-table" sortable>
      <thead>
        <tr class=table__input-general>
          <th colspan="5">Voyage details</th>
          <th colspan="3">Weather conditions</th>
          <th class="table__input-general-description" rowspan="2">General description / comments</th>
          <th class="actions" rowspan="2">Edit / delete record</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table__input-details">
          <td>Time <br> UTC</td>
          <td>Latitude <br> [&deg;&nbsp;,&nbsp;']</td>
          <td>Longitude <br> [&deg;&nbsp;,&nbsp;']</td>
          <td>Heading <br> [&deg;]</td>
          <td>SOG <br>[kt]</td>
          <!-- weather conditions -->
          <td>Wind force</td>
          <td>Sea state</td>
          <td>Visibility</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>

  </div>
  <div class="operation-buttons">
    <button class="new-record__btn">
            Add new record
        </button>
    <button class="voyage-details__button">
            Enter date and destination
        </button>
    <button class="ship-details__button">
            Set ship's details
        </button>
    <button class="export-button">
            Export to PDF
        </button>
  </div>
  <div class="ship-details__popup">
    <div id="ship-details__popup-closing-btn">X</div><br>
    <h2>Enter your ship's name and type</h2>
    <form>
      <label for="ship-type">Select your ship's type</label>
      <!-- Selection of ship type - to be modified upon submit -->
      <select name="ship-type" id="ship-type">
        <option value="M/V">Motor Vessel</option>
        <option value="M/T">Motor Tanker</option>
        <option value="S/V">Sailing Vessel</option>
        <option value="S/Y">Sailing Yacht</option>
        <option value="OSV">Offshore Support Vessel</option>
        <option value="DSV">Dive Support Vessel</option>
        <option value="PSV">Platform Supply Vessel</option>
        <option value="SOV">Service Operation Vessel</option>
        <option value="Tug">Tugboat</option>
      </select>
      <label for="ship-name">Enter your ship's name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="ship-name-input" placeholder="Enter your ship's name here" required><br>
      <button type="button" id="ship-details-submit-btn">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <!-- Pop up with date setting and destination -->
  <div class="voyage-details__popup">
    <div id="voyage-details__popup-closing-btn">X</div><br>
    <h2>Fill out inputs below to update voyage details</h2>
    <form>
      <label for="date">Enter date:</label>
      <input type="date" id="date-input" name="date" value="" min="2018-01-01" max="2021-01-01">
      <label for="destination">Enter your last port of call:</label>
      <input type="text" id="ship-destination-input__from" placeholder="Enter your last port of call">
      <label for="destination">Enter your current destination:</label>
      <input type="text" id="ship-destination-input__to" placeholder="Enter your current destination"><br>
      <button type="button" id="voyage-details__submit-btn">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <!--New record pop up-->
  <div class="new-record__popup">
    <div id="new-record__popup-closing-btn">X</div><br>
    <h2>Fill out inputs below to make a new record</h2>
    <form autocomplete="off">
      <label for="UTC-time">UTC Time  </label>
      <input type="text" name="UTC-time" placeholder="Enter time of the record" id="new-record__UTC-time">
      <label for="latitude">Latitude [&deg;&nbsp;,&nbsp;']  </label>
      <div class="latitude-container">
        <input type="text" name="latitude" placeholder="Enter latitude" id="new-record__latitude">
        <select class="north-south">
          <option value="N">N</option>
          <option value="S">S</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <label for="longitude">Longitude [&deg;&nbsp;,&nbsp;']  </label>
      <div class="longitude-container">
        <input type="text" name="longitude" placeholder="Enter longitude" id="new-record__longitude" title="Degrees and minutes">
        <select class="east-west">
          <option value="E">E</option>
          <option value="W">W</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <label for="heading">Heading [&deg;]  </label>
      <input type="text" name="heading" placeholder="Enter your heading" id="new-record__heading">
      <label for="SOG">Speed Over Ground [kt]  </label>
      <input type="number" name="SOG" placeholder="Enter your speed" min="-5" max="40" id="new-record__SOG">
      <label for="wind-force">Wind Force [B]  </label>
      <input type="number" name="wind-force" placeholder="Enter wind force" min="0" max="12" id="new-record__wind-force">
      <label for="sea-state">Sea State  </label>
      <input type="number" name="sea-state" placeholder="Enter sea state" min="0" max="9" id="new-record__sea-state">
      <label for="visibility">Visibility</label>
      <input type="text" name="visibility" placeholder="Enter visibility" id="new-record__visibility">
      <label for="remarks">General remarks </label>
      <textarea name="remarks" name="remarks" id="new-record__remarks" placeholder="Add remarks..."></textarea>
    </form>
    <button type="button" id="new-record__submit-btn">Submit record</button>
    <button type="button" id="edit-record">Edit record</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Works as a charm, I probably wouldn't ever think about it! Big thanks to you, and I'm back to finishing up the project! :)

Comment: welcome, glad I could hep, I too learned something :)